# Disk has disapeared, Raid 1 appears to have changed disks :( and emergency mode!

Tags: hard-drive, raid

What a muddle....I had managed to set up a Ubuntu 16 server utilising a software RAID 1=(`sda` & `sdb`)

Had added a second disc mounted to `/media/BackupDrive sdc`.

all with samba, all was well :)

But having tried to install cups and a `crontab` simple backup - somehow, where now booting in emergency mode, `sda` appears to have vanished and the raid now appears to be `sdb` and `sdc`

:(  please, please help!

```
cat /proc/mdstat  .....
Perso...
md1 : active raid 1 sdb2[1] sdc2[0]
...
md0: active raid 1 sdb2[1] sdc2[0]
...
```

`journalctl` says

```
Failed to mount  /media/Backup/Drive
```

and

```
iSCSI daemon with pid=1032started
```

*Have I goosed a HDD?*

Comment: WHERE did you backup to? You may have backed up to a boot drive(maybe `sda`, and overwritten most, if not all of `/boot`. Check all HDDs on another computer.